# checking whether tuple in the list in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have a list of variables as follows:

```
v = [('d',0),('i',0),('g',0)]
```

What I want is to obtain a vector of values, that gives the truth value of the presence of the variable inside the list.

So, if have another list say

```
g = [('g',0)]
```

The output of that should be

```
op(v,g) = [False, False, True]
```

P.S.

I have tried using `np.in1d` but it gives the following:

```
array([False, True, False, True, True, True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can use a list comprehension like following :

```
>>> v=[('d', 0), ('i', 0), ('g', 0)]
>>> g=[('t', 0), ('g', 0),('d',0)]
>>> [i in g for i in v]
[True, False, True]
```

Comment: What if I have a list of values in `g`

Comment: @PalashAhuja In that case you can sue `itertools.izip` checkout the edit!

Comment: The output is simply `[False]` for the second case. also, I am using python3 so izip is not required

Comment: @PalashAhuja You just need to check the membership of  elements of `v` in g. check the edit

Answer (score 1):

You can convert those lists to numpy arrays and then use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) like so -

```
import numpy as np

# Convert to numpy arrays
v_arr = np.array(v)
g_arr = np.array(g)

# Slice the first & second columns to get string & numeric parts.
# Use in1d to get matches between first columns of those two arrays;
# repeat for the second columns.
string_part = np.in1d(v_arr[:,0],g_arr[:,0])
numeric_part = np.in1d(v_arr[:,1],g_arr[:,1])

# Perform boolean AND to get the final boolean output
out = string_part & numeric_part
```

Sample run -

```
In [157]: v_arr
Out[157]: 
array([['d', '0'],
       ['i', '0'],
       ['g', '0']], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [158]: g_arr
Out[158]: 
array([['g', '1']], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [159]: string_part = np.in1d(v_arr[:,0],g_arr[:,0])

In [160]: string_part
Out[160]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [161]: numeric_part = np.in1d(v_arr[:,1],g_arr[:,1])

In [162]: numeric_part
Out[162]: array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [163]: string_part & numeric_part
Out[163]: array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Sorry if I have not explained clearly, but what if g had let's say `('g',1)` then this method stands invalid

Comment: @PalashAhuja So, with `v = [('d', 0), ('i', 0), ('g', 0)]` and `g = [('g', 1)]`, then the output must be all `False`, right?

Comment: Yes the output must be false